# SQL join between two tables with MAX in where clause

Tags: sql, db2

I have `table_A` with an `ID` column.

```
-----
ID
-----
id1
id2
id3
-----
```

I have another `table_B` which has `latest_sub_id` for every `id` in `table_A` along with a date.

```
---------------------------------
ID        SUB_ID     Date
---------------------------------
id1       sub_id_1   2015-01-03
id1       sub_id_2   2015-01-10
id2       sub_id_1   2015-01-02
id2       sub_id_2   2015-01-10
id2       sub_id_2   2015-01-12
id2       sub_id_3   2015-01-15
id3       sub_id_1   2015-01-09
id3       sub_id_2   2015-01-25
---------------------------------
```

I want to write a join query between the two tables, such that I get the `SUB_ID` value for given `ID` value on the `MAX(DATE)`.

The result should be:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 ID    SUB_ID
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 id1   sub_id_2      ---> as 10th Jan is the latest date for id1
 id2   sub_id_3      ---> as 15th Jan is the latest date for id2
 id3   sub_id_2      ---> as 25th Jan is the latest date for id3
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: note that if sub_id is an incrementing ID, then `select id, max(sub_id) from mytable group by id` is sufficient for the results you've asked for.

Comment: This is a classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, and [there are many existing answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937046/select-one-row-per-index-value-with-max-column-value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really seem to need the first table.

One way using a `where` clause is:

```
select b.*
from tableb b
where not exists (select 1 from tableb b2 where b2.id = b.id and b2.date > b.date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help.

```
create table #t (ID varchar(5), sub_id varchar(20), itemDate date)

insert into #t VALUES ('id1','sub_id_1','2015-01-03')
,('id1','sub_id_2','2015-01-10')
,('id2','sub_id_1','2015-01-02')
,('id2','sub_id_2','2015-01-10')
,('id2','sub_id_2','2015-01-12')
,('id2','sub_id_3','2015-01-15')
,('id3','sub_id_1','2015-01-09')
,('id3','sub_id_2','2015-01-25')


select #t.id, sub_id,itemdate from #t inner join (select id,max(itemdate) latest from #t group by id) grouped
on #t.ID = grouped.ID and itemdate = latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this :

```
select aaa.id, bbb.id, ....
from tableA aaa Left outer join tableB bbb on aaa.id = bbb.id AND (bbb.id, bbb.subId, bbb.Date) IN (select id, subId, MAX(Date) from tableB group by id, subId)
where ....
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested query is a way to go. No `WHERE` clause needed.

```
SELECT ID, SUB_ID, Date
FROM table_B tb
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ID, MAX(Date) as 'Date'
    FROM table_B
    GROUP BY ID) as t
ON tb.ID = t.ID AND tb.Date = t.Date
```

The MAX function also doesn't fit into the syntax of the `WHERE` clause.

You can find more in this answer: [SQL - Using MAX in a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18877320/1439748)

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
SELECT A.ID, B.SUB_ID, B.Date FROM table_A AS A
INNER JOIN table_B AS B ON (B.ID = A.ID)
INNER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT ID, MAX(Date) AS 'MaxDate' FROM table_B
GROUP BY ALL ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1
) AS MX ON (MX.ID = B.ID AND MX.[MaxDate] = B.Date)
```

Comment: Nope.  The `date` you'll end up with will be repeated for every `sub_id`, whereas the op wants only one `sub_id` (per base id).

Comment: That `HAVING` clause is ironic, given the op is trying to get the most-recent row.  Can you tell me why?  What problem will it cause?

Comment: The `HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1` clause eliminates rows with more than 1 Date value being equal to the `MAX(Date)` value for any `GROUP` of `ID`.